# Making indented panel lines for 3d printing

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, 3d-printing

I'm quite new to Blender but planning to use it for 3D printing, so I'm looking for a solution which will actually modify the geometry. I have created a couple of aircraft. I need to detail them with some panel lines but I don't know how to easily make an indented straight line.

existing model - https://www.shapeways.com/model/1051048/d21-drone.html?li=my-models&materialId=6

[image: panel lines position]

Comment: Looking at that model close up, the topology isn't so great. It seems to be made of all tris. I would recommend remodelling it as it is quite a simple shape. After that, take a look at the knife, inset and extrude tools.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I should have said, I'm aware the topology is shocking especially around the front where the wings start. As a beginner, I'm not sure how i managed to get so messed up around that area.  Thanks, I will investigate those tools.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tools you are asking about are quite simple, you can make loop cuts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>. Roll your mousewheel to create multiple cuts and use left click to confirm/right click to cancel.

[image]

Since Blender can handle ngons, if your shape is a flat hard surface, feel free to cut it. Activate the *Knife* took with <kbd>K</kbd>, click an edge as a starting point and then click another edge as the end point, when satisfied. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm.

[image]

You might also be interested in the *Inset* tool. This can be useful for giving your faces a bit of distance from the sharp edges so any further modifications don't look odd or modify parts of the mesh you don't want. Press <kbd>`I`</kbd> while selecting multiple edge loops or faces and use your mouse to adjust the inset level.

[image]

The *Extrude* tool is what you will use to create the indentations. Just select the face(s) and press <kbd>E</kbd>, you can use your mouse to adjust how far the extrusion goes in/out.

[image]

And all of those combined on a simple box model, produces this. Tri's aren't so bad when working with hard surface models but they make editing a pain.

[image]

Decent topology is a must when doing *3D printing*. See, [What exports does blender have for 3d printers?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/253/12).

Comment: For additional reading.. [What is the technical difference between an Ngon and a bunch of Tri's?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1684/12).