# Problem with creating edge rings on a model

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I always mess up my model in blender. At some point I manually add vertices on edges with subdivide and then I connect them with <kbd>J</kbd>, and sometimes I have to fill faces with <kbd>F</kbd>.

[image]

[image]

As you can see my model is a little bit messed up and this happens all the time. And I can't properly use the loop cut tool anymore.

Any idea how to fix this?

Update:

Here is the blend.file

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/25381

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because of two things.

1. Because you are using [N-gons](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/what-is-the-technical-difference-between-an-ngon-and-a-bunch-of-tris). N-gons perfectly fine when making hard surface models but when it comes on to topology, they get a bit difficult to work with.

   [image]
2. You have faces on the inside of your model. This is a no no and the *Edge Ring* tool will detect these when you are trying to make a ring and won't allow it.

   [image]

So to fix, you can use the *Knife tool* to try and cut the ngons into quads (See [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4959/12) on how to use the Knife tool), don't just select vertices and press <kbd>F</kbd>. Next, remove all inner faces of your model, you can just go into *Wireframe* view and select the faces and use <kbd>X</kbd> *> Faces*.

Trying to create an edge ring with inside face(s).

[image]

Creating an edge ring without inside faces.

[image]

Trying to add edge rings to an Ngon vs trying to add edge rings to quads.

[image]

Comment: There is a tool for selecting inner faces, in *Header > Select > Inner Faces*

Comment: This answer was helpful to me in working on a much simpler model. I was trying to loop cut a cube but when I turned on the tool it would do nothing. The reason? I had beveled off the cube corners (with simple slices, so the corners were triangles), so it was not really a cube anymore, and every surface was a polygon. There were no quads for the tool to work on. I guess the rule is loop cut before beveling.