# Why does this edge loop problem happen?

Tags: modeling, edges, faces, topology

So I've created a desk, and im looking to make a central partition, however when I'm trying to make the loop cut (ctrl+r) (to extrude them together, My loop cut refuses to run across one particular face. I've probably (definitely) not explained that very well, but i suppose my question is, why am i not getting the option to make a loop cut here? and if not, how do i make it happen?

Many thanks

Sam[image: what i've got]
[image: the problem]

[image: what i was hoping to happen]

Comment: You are probably dealing with unconnected geometry or have a face (or more) with more than 4 vertices (ngon). This gets asked quite often read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17870/loop-cut-wont-go-all-the-way-around and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7990/why-does-loop-cut-and-slide-ignore-some-faces-but-not-others and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33188/loop-cut-interrupted

Comment: im working from a cube though? any further ideas? is the a certain way to connect two edges? im thinkgin this may be the problem

Comment: It means you have to do some cleanup to your model. You either have duplicate geometry or deleted something somewhere leading to an NGon face