# Why does my loop subdivide not extend around the whole shape?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am createing a model which has a cylinder shape extruded inwards, and wanted to create some sharper edges around it. I tried using the loop subdivide tool (Ctrl + R) but the "loop" part of it is only reaching half-way along the inner edge

[image: Loop subdivide problem]

The top portion of this is divided into thirds for this, and I'm not sure why this is happening.

These appear to be 4 sided shapes, so I don't think it's an ngon problem.

Comment: Does this help? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17870/loop-cut-wont-go-all-the-way-around

Comment: Looks like you probably have double verts or something there

Comment: @gandalf3 can you point out where you see this? I'm pretty new to 3d modeling so I'm not really in touch with what to look for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have duplicated vertices. Here I ripped a few vertices (and moved them away which isn't the case in your model) to interrupt the flow of the loop cut:

[image]

This can be easily fixed by *Remove Doubles*.

Comment: I will be able to check later today if this is the case. Is `Remove Doubles` something I should hit periodically if I don't expect them? Or is there a more reliable way to detect they are present?

Comment: I used remove doubles, and it removed zero vertices. So I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Okay, I tried again, this time selecting my whole mesh first (instead of having nothing selected), and that removed 3 vertices, and now the edge loop moves around the whole way.

Answer (score 0):

This is most propably happening because you haven't extruded the whole thing at once, you have extruded it by parts. So you can try to just add a loop cut in this places as well. Or you can also try to press ( i ) and extrude inwards.