# Why can't I add cuts to a shape?

Tags: bezier-curves, vertices

I am trying to add cuts to a shape to give it a bent shape. The object is the back pane of a foldable chair.

[image]

But when I try to select the shape (L) and add cuts (ctrl + R), the cuts I add do not appear on the shape... but cut numbers show up in the text bar on the bottom.

[image]

Maybe there are other ways to do this, but I have a beginner level, and tried many different ways to do this already.

Among the other ways I tried to do this; I tried starting from a flat cube then added cuts but adjusting the top left and top right curves to the existing frame made the shape of the grid too skewed to later on give it a curved round shape.
I also tried selecting the excess angles on top with the C selection shape and removing them but it looked way too messy.
I also tried flattening two cylinders and I was planning on merging them together but that didn't work either.

The current shape I have, I got it by creating a thin torus, removing 3/4ths of it all around, and the inside faces, then I duplicated it and rotated it on the other side then joined the opposite vertices.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/17870/599

Comment: Loop cuts don't work with ngons.

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate. If it were me, I'd switch to edge select mode, select the two edges across the bottom, and subdivide them using the subdivide tool, and increasing the number of divisions to 3. Then using the three sets of vertices in the bottom edge, create the radial geometry for the back. (

Comment: can you make this an answer to be upvoted/accepted and close the question? thanks