# how to make a limit for the loop cut tool

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertex-groups

are there any way for making the loop cut not going to certain vertex group in the mesh ? as you see in the image when i click on ctrl + r the loop cut go through all the character from her head to her foot but i want to not add any new loop cut to the character head so are there any way for that ?

[image]

Comment: This is result of the Edge Flows. If you want to "stop" Loop Cut you will need to redirect it or stop it completely by using triangle.

Comment: Funny that we get this question, it is usually [the other way around](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17870/loop-cut-wont-go-all-the-way-around). Basically just do what those people unintentionally did. Create a triangle or a NGon, which I am pretty sure is generally an undesirable thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switch to Face Select Mode, select the faces you want to keep and hide them with <kbd>H</kbd>. Then do your loop cut. After that, reveal your faces with <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.

The loopcut will have added a new vertex but it will not have cut through. So, if you have hidden some quads, you will get an ngon. Not ideal but you can retopologize it later.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As long as the Edge Flow is intact the Edge Loops will continue utill reaching a break
 (Like Tri or N-Gon) So basicaly if you break the edge flow in two spots you can control where the edge loops will go.

[image]

Do it by pressing <kbd>K</kbd> for the Knife Tool and drawing a Tri one face above where you want your Edge Loop to stop then you Select the edges created with the Knife tool > <kbd>X</kbd>>`Dissolve Edges`