# Using GG to move an edge doesn't yield expected results

Tags: edges

I created an edge loop so that I can add a groove vertically. Just like the horizontal groove. I want it to be a thiner groove so after creating the loop I pressed `G > G` to slide along the face. This was the result. I did notice when creating the loop I had to do it twice because the loop didn't go from the top of my model to the bottom. I'm sure that's where the problem is I just don't know how to fix it. How do I fix my faces or edges to go the same way?

[image]

I don't know how this fixed it but I deleted these quads circled in red. Then deleted the loop cut and redid a loop cut and it worked. Can you explain why?

[image]

Comment: "*I did notice when creating the loop I had to do it twice because the loop didn't go from the top of my model to the bottom.*" <- That right there should be your warning sign. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17870/loop-cut-wont-go-all-the-way-around

Comment: Looks like your normals are not all facing the same direction.

Comment: You had a face with three vertices and another face with five vertices. You changed the mesh so the faces all had four vertices which plays best with loop cuts and other tools in Blender.

Comment: How do you see that? They all look like quads to me. @Dontwalk

Comment: @Funlamb [img]https://i.imgur.com/jvDwkdQ.jpg[/img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dontwalk pointed out:

> You had a face with three vertices and another face with five vertices. You changed the mesh so the faces all had four vertices which plays best with loop cuts and other tools in Blender.

I had a face overlapping another face and this cause my loop cut to not go all the through my model. Once i removed the extra face and redid my loop cut the problem was fixed.