# Why can't I create edge loops inside of my mesh

Tags: modeling

[image: Edge loops only go on the outside of the cube wall. The normals are facing the correct way.]

The edge loops do not go on the inside of the cube wall. I made the wall from a cube following a floor plan. I tried using the knife tool but the edges it generated were not able to be selected. What is a solution to this. The walls all have 4 vertices and are not n-gons.

Thanks

Blend File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ktpjiulkh9Ij2qSE3IGn35xmdYjVs1Ur/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you look, the wall that is unaffected by the loop cut _is_ an n-gon - there are two cuts on the top that don't come down the front side, leaving 2 extra vertices..

Comment: I tried to check that, but from looking at it below, it appears to have 4 vertices, I can add my blend file aswell if you need it.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17870/loop-cut-wont-go-all-the-way-around

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:
[image]

Loop cut only works on quads, but inner wall face has some extra verts. I assume you have a window or something on the other side.

You could fix your topology by having those loops continue all the way around. You usually want most of the mesh to be quads, exectly to not encounter problems such as this.

Comment: Makes sense, how would I do that though (continue loops)? I tried using the knife tool, but that wouldn't work for me.

Comment: Can you not finish the loops for the highlighted verts? Using knife tool is probably the best option. If that's not working, delete the face, subdivide the bottom edge to add 2 extra verts, then manualy create 3 faces for the inside wall.

Comment: Thank you, I just deleted the 'cube' wall structure and then extruded it from the surrounding walls and the loop cuts now work correctly.