# Loop cut being cut off?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create a loop cut across this whole face but it's stopping early?
[image: Screenshot of my failed loop cut]

Comment: If you share your project with https://blend-exchange.com/ it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @PepAndorra Sure thing: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=LZ6ae0mJ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/LZ6ae0mJ/)

Comment: There are several answers here on how the loop cut works... the narrow vertical face is not a quad, it's an n-gon. Read more here: [Loop-cut won't go all the way around](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17870/loop-cut-wont-go-all-the-way-around)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I read through what you sent but I'm still not sure how to fix my problem. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This narrow face is an ngon, the *Loopcut* operation don't cut through an ngon as it is not supposed to know where to cut, so you either need to dissolve these vertices, or use another tool like the *Knife* tool (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut through, <kbd>A</kbd> to cut orthogonally:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Tried that and it worked