# How do you prepare a model for 3D printing?

Tags: 3d-printing

Ive no idea how to prepare a model for 3D printing. 
Is the model supposed to be prepared in a specific way? If I want to print a model with meshes that intersect other meshes, would blender be able to print that? or does it not have to have any intersecting geometry?

Comment: I have heard that 3d printing favors the STL format and that it's really important that your mesh is closed. Meaning no openings between vertices or polygons.

Comment: Just put your title into google. Plenty of tutorials and instructions. This topic is very complex and out of scope of this site. If you have specific problem with 3d printing or mesh preparation then ask it here pls.

Comment: Enable the [3D printing toolbox addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/PrintToolbox) to help check for many common issues.

Comment: I think my answer here still stands. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253/what-exports-does-blender-have-for-3d-printers