# Is there any tutorial specifically for 3D printing mechanical objects?

Tags: 3d-printing

Can anyone suggest a source for one or more beginner tutorials aimed at the relatively basic task of creating simple mechanical parts (discs with radial holes, Archimedes screws, etc) for 3D printing?  I have no need of lighting, animation, et cetera.  I'm interested in making toys and silly little machines like the marble elevators on thingiverse.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Blender SE. I don't find your question precise enough, have you already modeled the objects? Which steps do you need a tutorial for?

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253/what-exports-does-blender-have-for-3d-printers. If you have any concrete question about modeling / another using Blender, ask it here. If you want to learn more about 3dprinting the first place to ask would be [3D Printing SE](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/) or google.

Comment: Yo might want to ask your question on the 3D printing SE, since it doesn't appear to be about Blender specificly.

Comment: Hi. thanks for responding.  I own a Lultbot Taz5 which I use for printing small gears with Gearotic (incredible program!).  I have some hand sketches for small mechanical parts and I want to turn them into STL files for printing.  Every tutorial I can find is focused mainly on lighting, animation, making realistic grass, et cetera.  I have no need for any of those things.  After going through a few of those, I tried my hand at the program and I keep getting errors about non-manifold objects and overhangs and all kinds of stuff that's meaningless to me because they are specific to 3D printing.

Comment: The DVD on Blender for 3D printing is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!  I just purchased a copy.