# What are the best Blender add-ons or plugins to use for 3D printing?

Tags: 3d-printing

I just started learning Blender and actually still learning. I want to use Blender in order to 3D print my designs. I want to know what are the best add-ons or plugins to have in order to assure that my designs are printable and good to go.

Comment: Pretty sure that depends on what sort of 3d printer you are using.

Comment: A "3d print toolbox" addon ship by default with recent Blender versions, you just have to enable it.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35415/why-is-blender-so-popular-for-3d-printing and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253/what-exports-does-blender-have-for-3d-printers